# msiexec.exe hangs at 0 percent cpu while updating software

Tags: installshield, windows-installer

Okay, I have searched for a solution to my problem on the internet and could not find an answer to my specific problem. When I am trying to install something that uses Windows Installer (**msiexec.exe**) the installer never makes it to the progress bar. When I run task manager and look at the **msiexec.exe** they are **both running at 0% cpu**, and not doing anything. (Both meaning the 32bit and the 64 bit versions). **The setup program is stuck on "*Setup is preparing the InstallShield Wizard. Please Wait.*"**

I don't have any other installations running, and I have waited hours longer than it should have taken to initialize, and install. So waiting will accomplish nothing.

Sometimes when I terminate the 32bit msiexec.exe, the installShield would continue but sometime during the installation it will hang with the 32 bit msiexec **running again at 0% (zero percent) CPU usage**. And then I would end the 32 bit process again and it would continue onward, until it hangs again but this time there is no 32 bit msiexec in the Task Manager. And if i terminate the 64 bit MsiExec the program would alert me saying "Error 1719. Windows Installer service could not be accessed. Contact your support personnel to verify that it is properly registered and enabled."

The Windows Installer Service ***is*** registered and Enabled it only pops up when i terminate the 64 bit MsiExec that is doing nothing. Sorry if this is too wordy but I am putting in my specific problem. All other solutions were for those whose msiexec were running at 25% - 100% cpu, **My problem is that it is doing NOTHING, it is running at ZERO % CPU**

Comment: Try enabling MSI logging and see if you see anything useful (or at all.) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/223300/how-to-enable-windows-installer-logging.  It sounds like the issue is probably more with InstallShield, however.  You might also look to make sure there's not a hidden (under something) UAC dialog waiting for you to click on.

Comment: The last entry is MSI (c) (1C!8C) [16:10:18:491]: Creating MSIHANDLE (36) of type 790531 for thread 3468

Comment: I don't really know what i am suppose to look for

Comment: I already clicked on Yes on consent.exe (Grant Admin privilage)

Comment: Do I need to show you the log?

Comment: Having us read a log here is really beyond the scope of what StackOverflow is, at least in mind - you might do better at Super User.  As a parting suggestion, you might get some hints on reading the log at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc535232.aspx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I have found out how to fix my problem. it seems that the Volume Shadow Copy service (which is what windows uses to make backups of.. well.. windows) might be hanging.

My solution was to open taskmanager and click services. look for **VSS** right click it, click restart. Then I ran the installer again and it worked!!!

Comment: same problem here. solved killing vssc. thank you